# Counting number of grouped rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

In a table xyz I have a row called components and a labref row which has labref number as shown here

Table xyz

```
labref             component
NDQA201303001          a
NDQA201303001          a
NDQA201303001          a
NDQA201303001          a
NDQA201303001          b
NDQA201303001          b
NDQA201303001          b
NDQA201303001          b
NDQA201303001          c
NDQA201303001          c
NDQA201303001          c
NDQA201303001          c
```

I want to group the components then count the rows returned which equals to 3, I have written the below SQL query but it does not help achieve my goal instead it returns 4 for each component

```
SELECT DISTINCT component, COUNT( component ) 
FROM `xyz`
WHERE labref = 'NDQA201303001'
GROUP BY component
```

The query returns

Table xyz

```
labref         component   COUNT(component)       
NDQA201303001   a           4
NDQA201303001   b           4
NDQA201303001   c           4
```

What I want to achieve now is that from the above result, the rows are counted and 3  is returned as the number of rows, Any workaround is appreciated

Comment: You mean you want 3 as an output in this case?

Comment: select count(DISTINCT component) from `xyz`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to do -

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            DISTINCT component
        FROM
            `multiple_sample_assay_abc`
        WHERE
            labref = 'NDQA201303001'
    ) AS DerivedTableAlias
```

---

You can also avoid subquery as suggested by @hims056 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16584882/1369235)

Comment: @Kshitij - Why to use subquery when we can do [it directly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16584882/1369235)?

Comment: hims056' solution is the better one - avoid subquerys if you're able to

Comment: Add alias after closing parenthesis.

Comment: The reason for this answer is that it will work when you need a having clause.  The [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16584882/1369235) relies on being able to rewrite the query without a having clause.

Comment: @MarlinPierce: Just to be curious, may I know an example of the scenario you have mentioned?

Comment: The case is if instead of "WHERE labref = 'NDQA201303001'" you wanted all labref values but filtering for those with count = 3.  With Kshitij's answer you can remove the WHERE clause from the sub-query, then the outer query can GROUP BY labref, and a HAVING clause can filter for the values with count = 3.

Answer (score 149):

Try this simple query without a sub-query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT component) AS TotalRows
FROM xyz
WHERE labref = 'NDQA201303001';
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9cb69/1)

Comment: Of course this is the best solution, because it doesn't require a subquery.

Comment: Best Solution. This solution should be accepted as this is simpler and better approach

Comment: This will work if you don't have "GROUP BY". If query has "Group By" then all rows will have 1.

Comment: @hims056 Question is asked with "GROUP BY component"

For example:: 
if we have data like
 `(id, component, labref)
(1, 1, 'NDQA201303001'),
(2, 1, 'NDQA201303001'),
(3, 2, 'NDQA201303001'),
(4, 2, 'NDQA201303001');`
and then if we execute
`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT component) AS TotalRows FROM xyz WHERE labref = 'NDQA201303001' group by component`
It results like TotalRows  1,1

Comment: I'm on same scenario and @Bala is right, this solution wont work if query has "Group By". -1

Comment: @hims056 I concocted a fiddle here where it does not work: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8295c9/2/1 - Only the 3rd SQL provides the correct result for: "How many distinct values occurs more than once?"

Comment: It is a bit off topic from the question though, but still the answer I went looking for when I first found this answer. :)

Comment: @JohnySkovdal - You've made a fiddle to answer a different question, so saying this answer "does not work" is incorrect. As your fiddle shows, this answer correctly reports the number of distinct values.

Comment: @JoelEnanodJr, Bala - You wouldn't use "Group By" with this answer; this answer is an *alternative* approach, that doesn't need (nor tolerate) "Group By" in the query. OP only used "Group By" as *an attempt* to get the answer they need. Combining "Group By" with "Count(Distinct)" is not meaningful; Remove "Group By" from your query.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it's been a while, so I don't know my reasoning back then, and I think I might have mistaken some of the commenters as the OP. What I meant to say: If you query is more complex and `GROUP BY` is needed to narrow it down to the data you want to count, the fiddle provides an alternative that allows that: sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8295c9/2/1 - if it's not the case though, this answer is the better/simpler approach to pick.

Comment: Note that rows with `component = NULL` will not be counted.

Answer (score 12):

I found the solution.
So, if you want to count quantity of groups, not quantity of elements in each group, and return duplicate value to every group record in result table, you should use [OVER()](https://www.codeexplained.net/use-count-sql-without-group-clause/) clause on you'r count function.

So, for example above the solution would be

```
SELECT component, COUNT(*) OVER() as number_of_components FROM `xyz` 
WHERE labref = 'NDQA201303001' 
GROUP BY component
```

I suppose that works with any query that use GROUP BY, additional info, check in the link above.

Comment: This is the correct way of doing this. Works even when using `limit x`.

Comment: Note that you need to be on MySQL 8+ to use `OVER()` (and other window functions).

Comment: It didn't worked.

Comment: @menoktaokan check your sql version and your query

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`num_rows`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-result.num-rows.html).

If you do it using this method, You don't have to modify the query in any way.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT DISTINCT component, COUNT( component ) 
    FROM `xyz`
    WHERE labref = 'NDQA201303001'
    GROUP BY component")){

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* close result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: Shorter code if *nest* selects:  `select count(1) from ( ... ) t;` will yield row count of any query [with some limitations, specifically inner query must not have duplicate column names], where "..." is the query you are counting. For performance, can also change inner `SELECT DISTINCT component, COUNT( component ) FROM` to `SELECT DISTINCT component FROM`.

Comment: It should also be noted that bringing in a large table into PHP may hit an overload memory limit for PHP and "Fatal Error" the code.  Easier on memory to allow MySQL to count the rows.

Comment: Because that gives you total rows returned from table, not total rows in table matching the query. Try adding a `limit 10` of a query that has 1000.

Answer (score -1):

There is also:

```sql
SELECT `labref`, `component`, COUNT(*) as `count`
  FROM `xyz`
  WHERE labref = 'NDQA201303001'
  GROUP BY `component`;
```

Which should return:

| labref | component | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NDQA201303001 | a | 4 |
| NDQA201303001 | b | 4 |
| NDQA201303001 | c | 4 |

And, bonus points (I hope), no subqueries!

[Based on this source](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-group-by.php).

Answer (score -2):

Select  labref , component ,Count(*) as Counts From xyz Group by labref , component